# how to transform a mixed model estimate into a correlation?

Tags: r, correlation, mixed-model

With the following mixed model

```
mod <- lmer(sales1 ~ price1 + (1|store), oranges)
summary(mod)

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 store    (Intercept)  2.251   1.500   
 Residual             30.963   5.564   
Number of obs: 36, groups:  store, 6   

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  43.1069     8.3779 31.5104   5.145 1.36e-05 ***
price1       -0.6421     0.1621 32.1123  -3.961 0.000389 ***
```

is it possible to transform the `Estimate` of `price1` into a correlation coefficient?

Comment: The estimates of variance of random intercept and error are needed.

Comment: @user158565, I have edited my question and added the output of random effects. How would you use this information to get the correlation?

Comment: The correlation is 2.251/(30.963+2.251). It seems you do not need random intercept. (2.251 with SE=1.50)

Comment: Thanks @user158565, but is this really the correlation between `price1` and `sales1`? The estimate of the fixed effect is highly significant, but the correlation is only 2.251/(30.963+2.251) = 0.06777263. This doesn't seem very likely, am I missing something?

Comment: 2.251/(30.963+2.251) = cor(sales1_i, sales1_j) when i and j from the same store. I do not know the definition of  correlation between price1 and sales1 when model $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X_1 + \gamma + \epsilon$ is fit.

Comment: Thanks @user158565, what is `i` and `j` in your comment above? I'm trying to replicate the correlation value calculated above, but do not understand what `sales1_i` and `sales1_j` should be

Comment: Also, do you mean that there is no way to get a correlation between sales1 and price1 when fitting a mixed model like the one above? In linear regression it would simply be the square root of R squared

Comment: Your response variable is `sales1`. sales1_i, sales1_j are two sales1 from the same store. You have 36 sales1 and 6 stores. So some stores have more than one sales1.

Comment: I do not how know how to define  a correlation between sales1 and price1  when fitting a mixed model .